# Split text file using batch

Tags: batch-file, text, split

I'm trying to split the following data in a text file into two seperate files. One file should contain the last 4 lines which end with =x and =newcase and the other should contain the remaining lines that begin with 1515... Any idea's will be appreciated

```
1515861=Nomura Qatar Employment Advice
1515863=Nomura Bahrain Employment Advice
1515869=GSCEC . Gozzo Impianti S.p.A. - Conference Centre Project
1517106=Exterran - General Employment Advice
OFFICE=Office=X
NEW=New Case=X
OFF=Office=X
1111111=New Case
```

Answer (score 0):

```
type "c:\file" | findstr /i /e /c:"=x" >part1
type "c:\file" | findstr /i /b /c:"2525" >part2
```